# You must install or update .NET to run this application popup while opening MAUI windows application

Tags: maui, .net-8.0

I Have upgraded my existing MAUI application to .NET 8.0 and generated bundle file using below command from Command Line

```
dotnet publish -c Release -p:Platform=x64 -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0
```

I have installed the application using MSIX/Power shell.

While opening the application it is asking for install or update .NET like as below image

[image]

But before upgrading with .NET 7.0 the popup is not showing while opening the application.

Expected Behavior :
While opening the application it should not ask for to download

Please help us with this.

Comment: This would be expected if you try to run a framework dependent assembly without the framework installed. What is your actual question? Did you intend to build a self contained program? Are you asking why .Net 7 is installed but not .Net 8?

Comment: @JonasH Yes with .NET 7.0 it is not asking for popup to download, but with .NET 8.0 it is asking how can we mitigate that.

Comment: Install .Net 8, either thru the installer, manually, or some other channel. Or deploy as self contained, bundling the entire framework with your application.

Comment: @JonasH How can we do this "deploy as self contained, bundling the entire framework with your application"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `--self-contained` to the publish command line to create a self contained application, that contains the required parts of the framework, and can therefore be deployed without the need for additional installations. You may also need to add `-r win-x64` to specify the platform.

See the [deployment guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) for an overview of the deployment models and further details about the commands to use.